# Threads and Multi-Threads issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm building a program for scanning IP addresses. I built a class that checks the ports of

a given IP address. I run this class in loop as thread. I obviously blocking the amount of

thread that can be run in parallel. The problem is that always the thread returns an exit

code: 259, and after half a minute or so, the program hangs.

I tried to search in google, forums, and here what the code 259 means. So i found in some

forums that it simply return code that not meaning any thing. In other forums i see that is

means that there a problem with using a lot of memory. So i try to use only 2 threads in

paralel. It still doesnt work. I try to see another methods to work with threads, so i read

about threads pool, i change the code to use threads pool, but it still not work. I of

course made sure that in class i dont use global variableas.

Code :

```
   private void Get_Port_With_Status_Thread_Inventer()
    {

        for (int Thread_Cnt_Get_Port_N_Status = 1; Thread_Cnt_Get_Port_N_Status < IP_Address.Length + 1; Thread_Cnt_Get_Port_N_Status++)
        {

            if (Open_Threads_Port_N_Status_Counter >= Max_Thread_Allowed)
            {
               Thread_Cnt_Get_Port_N_Status--;
               continue;
            }

            Thread New_Port_N_Status_Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Get_Port_With_Status_Thread));
            New_Port_N_Status_Thread.Start(Thread_Cnt_Get_Port_N_Status);

            Open_Threads_Port_N_Status_Counter++;
        }

        End_Get_Port_N_Status_Inventer = true;
    }

   private void Get_Port_With_Status_Thread(object Index_On_Array_Obj)
    {

        int Index_On_Array = (int)Index_On_Array_Obj;

        string IP_Address_Str = IP_Address[Index_On_Array - 1];


        IPEndPoint IP_Address_Connect_Data_Base = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP_Address_Str), 80);

        Socket Socket_IP_Address_Connect_Data_Base = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        string Ports_Rep_Index = 80.ToString();

        DateTime Current_New_Now_Seconds = DateTime.Now.Date;

        try
        {
            Socket_IP_Address_Connect_Data_Base.Connect(IP_Address_Connect_Data_Base);
            Socket_IP_Address_Connect_Data_Base.Disconnect(true);

            IP_Port[Index_On_Array - 1] = "Port 80 - Live";
        }

        catch (SocketException g)
        {
            IP_Port[Index_On_Array - 1] = "Port 80 - Dead";
        }

        Open_Threads_Port_N_Status_Counter--;
    }
```

Comment: Aargh - the Upper_Case_With_Underscore_Variable_Names - they burn! (Seriously, it's a good idea to follow the naming conventions of the language you're writing in...) Additionally, you should tell us what you've done to diagnose the issue. Have you added any logging? Tried debugging? What do you mean by "the thread returns an exit code 256"?

Comment: This code has some serious problems. As I read it you almost immediately kill each thread. Using an not thread-safe shared boolean.

Comment: Probably you want `IP_Address_Bool_Port_N_Status = true;` at the end of the function, not at its very beginning. But anyway, this code is nonsense - e.g.: Why start a thread and then actively wait for it?

Comment: No , where you see that i kill thread ?

Comment: @BartoszKP becuase I need that the thread will get Added_Btn_Cnt_Port_N_Status integer , but if i run threads without checking if they get Added_Btn_Cnt_Port_N_Status integer , before they will be sufficient to get the added_Btn_Cnt_Port_N_Status integer this variable will change , think about it .

Comment: Have you tried using asynchronous connections instead of spawning thread for each connection?

Comment: &John Smith  how it telp me  i run a lot of ip addresses . so i must to create connection for each ip address .

Comment: @Anri2016 You've invented your own strange problem by implementing communication between threads incorrectly, and now you're trying to solve it in an even more incorrect way. I suggest you rethink your design completely.

Comment: @BartoszKP what incorrect there ?? see simple thing . you run multiple threads , and all of them use global variable , they use the global variable and change its value , and then use it , what your solution for that ??

Comment: @BartoszKP so if it cant solve the problem you can explain what wrong there and post correct code ? think about other people that have the same problem ...

Comment: @Anri2016 You are running these multiple threads one-by-one in sequence, waiting for each one of them to stop immediately after you start it. This makes the whole idea of multithreading useless here. Your problem with shared integer can be solved by simply passing the value to the threads as their parameter instead. It's hard to say if other people will have the same problem, because it's completely unclear where and how the "error 259" or whatever comes up. And it's a very localized issue, resulting from your misunderstanding of multithreading concepts.

Comment: @BartoszKP - You mean to : New_Port_N_Status_Thread.Abort(); ??? i want to delete it because i write it wrong , it doesnt a part of my code , i tried to edit it . but some one block me to edit this code ....  so please overlook about it , and if you can please edit it , because it really make there problem .

Comment: @Anri2016 It was because a suggested edit was pending. It's now accepted so you should be able to edit your post.

Comment: Asynchronous connections will not block your current thread, so you can have multiple connections in one thread. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: @John Smith  - ok , but then i need to check one ip address each time , but i want multiple ip address each time .

Comment: @BartoszKP - ok , i find how to passing integer to threads . i dont abort the thread - it wasnt a part of my code - i write it here mistakenly . The problem still remain .

Comment: @John Smith - i will check your idea .

Comment: @Anri 2016 Any reason you can't check multiple IP addresses?

Comment: @John Smith no ' it doesnt help me , but thank you :)

Comment: @BartoszKP - the solution was simply - dont use debugger , so instaed of give me down vote and tell me that im misunderstanding of multithreading concepts , you can now see what were the problem . and its not localized issue , think about programmers that write their code correctly and they use lot a of threads at a time , but they use debugger ??

Comment: @John Smith thank you but i solve the problem , i simply needed to run the program without debugger !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was simply . Dont run multiple threads with debugger , so if you have Microsoft

Visual Studio and you want run a lot of threads , run the program without the debugger !

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop in Get_Port_With_Status_Thread_Inventer is essentially blocking the current the thread it was called on until you are finished processing the ip addresses.  Anytime you need to use multi-threading in C# you should use [tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

For your problem, you'd be better off using a [parallel foreach loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    class Status
    {
        public IPAddress IpAddress { get; set; }
        public bool? IsAlive { get; set; }
    }

    private Status[] ipAddresses = new Status[]
    {
        new Status()
        {
            IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1")
        },
        new Status()
        {
            IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2")
        },
        new Status()
        {
            IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3")
        },
    };



    private void scanPorts()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(ipAddresses, scanPort);
    }

    private void scanPort(Status status)
    {
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(status.IpAddress, 80);
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                   SocketType.Stream,
                                   ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            socket.Disconnect(true);

            status.IsAlive = true;
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            status.IsAlive = false;
        }
    }
```

The Parallel.ForEach method takes an IEnumerable (like an array or a list) and calls a method for each element in the array in it's own thread.  The .NET libraries handle creating, running and destroying the threads for you.  The only thing you have to worry about is how to share your data between threads correctly.

The Status class I made helps to keep the IPAddress in sync with whether the program can connect to port 80 or not.  The default value for IsAlive is null.  You do not need to worry about passing the index from one thread to the next.

Comment: Thank you , but i already find the solution and its work great : dont use the debugger when im use a lot of threads at a time !