# Advanced IP Scanner - IP , Ports and shared folders

Tags: shared-directory, port-scanning

picture: https://sites.google.com/site/visualvisiojepages/

I want to know what the second line says the IP address, for example, this shared file? If possible, to explain what the name "NetDvrV3" and (mini_httpd/1.19 19dec2003) mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part "NetDvrV3"is the Title of the Webpage they are serving.

The second part "(mini_httpd/1.19 19dec2003)" means they are using [mini_httpd](http://www.acme.com/software/mini_httpd/) as the http server.

*edit* Reading your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839432/threads-and-multi-threads-issue) question, you probably whant to know how to get the data?

You can find the "NetDvrV3" in the HTML in the header: `<title>NetDvrV3</title>`

The server can be found in the HTTP Response from the server: `Server: mini_httpd/1.19 19dec2003`

Comment: can you please tell me how to identify if they using this http server ?

Comment: and also what is NetDvrV3 ? please answer , its very important to me .

Comment: for example in the 3rd title they use the same http server (mini http) but the first use NetDvrV3 and the second Hd_Client ?

Comment: Its like I said. Open the [url](http://bzq-116-168-31-117.red.bezeqint.net/) in your browser. The thing at the top of the browser is the title of the page. This page has "Advanced IP Scanner - IP, Ports,...." as title, that page has "NetDvrV3" as title. And "mini_httpd/1.19 19dec2003" means: Enter they are using mini_httpd as a server. If its something different, enter the string into google and see what comes up.